# MySQL update values in array

Tags: php, mysql

my array in DB looks like this:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:6:"first";i:1;s:9:"second";}
```

So output is like:

```
1 => first
2 => second
```

How can I update eg. only 1st value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by array in DB. Could you explain a bit more about that?

Comment: `a:2:{i:0;s:6:"first";i:1;s:9:"second";}` <- this is a value in column meta_value. When I add new position it will be eg. `a:3:{i:0;s:6:"first";i:1;s:9:"second";i:2;s:5:"third";}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string in your DB is a [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array. You first need to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it and then you can modify the values.